# Discord Python Bot: How to move specific users mentioned by the author of the message

Tags: python, bots, discord, discord.py

I am looking for a way to allow a user to move him or her self and another user to a different voice channel. I already got the command to work for the author of the message, but I am having trouble finding out a way to move another user in the same message. The idea is that the user would be able to type "n!negotiate [Other User]" and it would move the author and the other user to the Negotiation channel.

I would love some help with how I might be able to do this. The code is provided below excluding the tokens and ids.

Code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio
import time


Client = discord.Client() #Initialise Client 
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "n!") #Initialise client bot and prefix


@client.event 
async def on_ready():
    print("Logged in as:")
    print(client.user.name)
    print("ID:")
    print(client.user.id)
    print("Ready to use!")

@client.event
async def on_message(check): #Bot verification command.
    if check.author == client.user:
        return
    elif check.content.startswith("n!check"):
        await client.send_message(check.channel, "Nations Bot is online and well!")

async def on_message(negotiation): #Negotiate command. Allows users to move themselves and other users to the Negotiation voice channel.
    if negotiation.author == client.user:
        return
    elif negotiation.content.startswith("n!negotiate"):
        author = negotiation.author
        voice_channel = client.get_channel('CHANNELID')
        await client.move_member(author, voice_channel)

client.run("TOKEN")
```

Comment: The Negotiate command is the section I am highlighting.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `discord.ext.commands`.  You're importing it, but not actually using any of the features.

```
from discord.ext import commands
import discord

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "n!") #Initialize bot with prefix

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def check(ctx):
    await bot.say("Nations Bot is online and well!")

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def negotiate(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    voice_channel = bot.get_channel('channel_id')
    author = ctx.message.author
    await bot.move_member(author, voice_channel)
    await bot.move_member(member, voice_channel)

bot.run('TOKEN')
```

Here we use a [converter](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/commands.html#converters) to accept a `Member` as input.  Then we resolve the author of the message from the [invocation context](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/commands.html#invocation-context) and move both `Member`s to the voice channel.

Comment: Thank you! It worked with no problems. I will use @bot.command from now on.